# Issue with VS 2015 Project/Solution build definition in TFS 2010 Server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, build-definition

I'm getting an issue with TFS 2010 Build Definition which is not copying dlls properly for project in VS 2015. Initially I had an issue like all the compiler dlls are putting together in bin folder and I'm getting application level errors. Once I moved compiler dlls (csc.exe, *.config,*.CodeAnalysis.dll,...) Roslyn folder inside bin folder (Project\bin\Roslyn), application working successfully. My Roslyn folder is creating outside my project root directory.

Folder structure:

......\Build\Roslyn

......\Build\_PublishedWebsite\project_folder\bin

I have created a post build command to move this Roslyn inside bin and its moved successfully. but still a copy of files under Roslyn are available in bin too and its failing my application to work properly.

Any help. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: As a temporary fix, I have added post build command to remove the files. if exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Microsoft*CodeAnalysis*dll" del /F "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Microsoft*CodeAnalysis*dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix, 
I have added post build command to remove the files and it's working successfully.

```
if exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\MicrosoftCodeAnalysisdll" del /F "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\MicrosoftCodeAnalysisdll"
```